# questions about android:textAppearance

Tags: android, android-layout

Have anyone seen this kind of style code before? What does '?android:textAppearance' mean? I got this piece of code from apktool when I try to extract the resource of a apk file.

```
<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question mark indicates a reference to a theme attribute.

Comment: Do you mean the android:textAppearance in myButtonStyle will be the same to the attribute android:textAppearance I set in my theme.

Comment: Yes, it might look like `<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomButton</item>` in the attribute `<style>` of your theme

Answer (score 0):

it refers to a text-style defined in android package.